# Index of / shown instead of index.html in apache 2.4.7

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04

The document root in `000-default.conf` is `/var/www/html`. The Directory  is set as `<Directory /var/www/html/>`. There is an `index.html` in `/var/www/html`. However apache 2.4.7 shows me the directory listing of / instead of the index.html in `/var/www/html` for the website. What should I be looking to change?

Answer (score 0):

Add `DirectoryIndex index.html` to your default virtual host definition or global config. Check whether you have *mod_dir* enabled.

Comment: I do have `DirectoryIndex index.html` in my virtual host  defintiion and mod_dir is enabled as well.

Comment: Are use sure the DNS name used in browser isn't defined in another virtual host? Please provide contents of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mod_dir.* files and the entire /etc/apache/sites-enabled/000-default.conf.

Comment: I managed to solve it. The problem was within the `Directory` directive in `000-defualt.conf`, `AllowOverride` was set to `None`. Once I set it to `All` everything worked as expected. Thanks a lot for the attention to the question - not sure why it was down-voted.

Comment: Setting `AllowOverride` only changes whether *.htaccess* files can override config file settings. You should especially avoid setting it to `All`, as it is potentially insecure.